# C program IPC message

Tags: c, ipc

I am using IPC for 2 programs communication.

**Snippet of my code for sender:**

```
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;  
key_t key_id;  
struct msgbuf sbuf;  
size_t buflen;  
key_id = 1235;  

sbuf.mtype = 1;  

if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)  
{               die("msgsnd");  

}  
else {
    mvprintw(8, 0, "%s", "                  ");
    mvprintw(8, 0, "%s", sbuf.mtext);           
}
```

**Receiving end:**

```
if ((msqid = msgget(key_id, 0666)) < 0)  
   die("msgget()");         //break;

//Receive an answer of message type 1.  

if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0)  
    die("msgrcv");  
mvprintw(curr_row + 1, 0, "Cleaning process monitor: %s", rcvbuffer.mtext);
```

The communication is working perfect but the message received at receiver's end is not fully received.

If i am sending "Hello" it receives only "H"
My buffer size is 200

Comment: What does `rcvbuffer` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare struct msgbuf directly with mtext size 1

```
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[1];    /* message data */ 
};
```

What you need to do is to declare a long char array in your structure, and then convert it to void*

For example,

```
struct msgbuf {
    long type;
    char mtext[200];
};

struct msgbuf mybuf;
// set type, store data in mtext

msgsnd(msqid, (void*)&mybuf, sizeof(msgbuf)+1, IPC_NOWAIT)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but that did not resolve my problem. I am compiling code using gcc and operating system is Ubuntu. My buffer size is =  buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ; Declared as : size_t buflen;